# Why take electric field as $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ in parallel plate capacitor made up of conductor?

Tags: electrostatics

I specifically ask this question because I've seen that when we ask that why electric field outside the parallel plate capacitor is zero then they subtract $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ with the same term. Shouldn't we subtract by taking just $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. From the question and the (unnecessarily snarky) comments that you made to it, you seem to know how this is calculated. Where *exactly* do you think that calculation went wrong?  We don't "take" the electric field as anything. We compute it (as you seem clearly to know).

Answer (score 0):

Just take one plate and apply Gauss' law to a cylinder with the bases parallel to the plate and use the symmetry. What happens when you add another plate? (Superposition principle)

Comment: I know that applying the gauss theorem, I can find the electric field value for the infinite plane sheet, and sigma by 2 × epsilon nought is the electric field value for a sheet made up of non conductor, not of conductor, now re-read my question please.

Comment: It works also with a infinite conducting sheet

Comment: How can we take sigma by 2 ×epsilon nought when it is conductor? Shouldn't we go with sigma by epsilon nought? Also, if we take just sigma by epsilon nought then electric field inside the conductor should be 2×sigma by epsilon nought.

Comment: Take a infinite plane capacitor. The plates have the same sigma. Now consider a cylinder with one base inside the plate (so that the electric field is zero) and another between the plates. This is different from bidimensional plates with infinitesimal thickness (that is what I had understood)